# Where does Sentry store the default domain?

Tags: django, sentry

I've setup sentry, but I typo'd on the first page where it asked me to set the default domain that it would use. I can't seem to find that stored anywhere - it's not in config.yml or the database, that I can see.

Where is it stored?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know where that initial value is stored, but I managed to override it by setting in sentry.conf.py:

```
SENTRY_URL_PREFIX
```

and in config.yml:

```
system.url-prefix
```

(It looks like either works, but the second is the preferred format going forward?)